# Extract names of second [given] level of nested list in R

Tags: r, nested-lists, names

I have a nested list. Each level of this list is named (as in provided dummy example). I want to extract the names (unique) from the 2nd level of my initial list, so I will be able to use them in some further operations.

I know how to do it in two steps, but I wonder whether there is more efficient/elegant solution. Also I wonder whether the regex approach would be faster (I am noob at regex).

Here is a dummy list:

```
x <- list(one = list(one_1 = list(seq = 1:9, start = 1, end = 5), 
one_2 = list(seq = 2:11, start = 2, end = 6), one_3 = list(
    seq = 3:12, start = 3, end = 7)), two = list(two_1 = list(
seq = 1:13, start = 8, end = 222), two_2 = list(seq = 1:14, 
start = 13, end = 54)))
```

And here is my code:

```
allnames <- names(rapply(x, function(x) head(x, 1)))
desirednames <- unique(sapply(strsplit(allnames, ".", fixed=TRUE), "[", 2))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `purrr::map_depth`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_depth(x, 1, names) %>% unlist(use.names = F)

#> [1] "one_1" "one_2" "one_3" "two_1" "two_2"
```

Comment: Why not `map(x, names)`?

Answer (score 8):

Solution for second level in `base` R:

```
unlist(lapply(names(x), function(n) names(x[[n]])))
[1] "one_1" "one_2" "one_3" "two_1" "two_2"
```

Comment: Isn't unlist more "costly" than purrr::map approach?

Comment: No need to load a package ! You can check using `microbenchmark` package on small and big dataset

Comment: `unlist(lapply(x, names))` or `unname(unlist(lapply(x, names)))`

Answer (score 3):

A concise way of doing this:

```
unlist(lapply(x, \(x) attributes(x)[['names']])) 
#    one1    one2    one3    two1    two2 
# "one_1" "one_2" "one_3" "two_1" "two_2"
```

If the list elements just have the `"names"` attribute, this simplifies to:

```
unlist(lapply(x, attributes))
# one.names1 one.names2 one.names3 two.names1 two.names2 
#    "one_1"    "one_2"    "one_3"    "two_1"    "two_2"
```

If the names annoy you, pipe it into `unname`.

```
unlist(lapply(x, attributes)) |> unname()
# [1] "one_1" "one_2" "one_3" "two_1" "two_2"
```